# libGDX GWT compile error that appears to be related to com.badlogic.gdx.utils.AtomicQueue<T>

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I have created a little game using libGDX and I try to compile the html project using GWT compile.

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.utils.AtomicQueue<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe also Push this to libgdx issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AtomicQueue is not compatible with GWT, you'll have to use another type of queue or not target GWT.